# What is this method System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessAsyncRequest()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using new relic to monitor my website and this method is the bottleneck on 80% of my web requests, even on simple GET requests, what does this do?

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessAsyncRequest()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304357/what-is-system-web-mvc-mvchandler-processasyncrequest)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Dude which version are you using ? 
It was a known issue in previous versions.
Upgrade to their latest agent (version 2.0.9.15) - is now available and should fix this issue.

Comment: I have latest agent version 2.10.40.0 and still most of my bottlenecks are System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest()

Comment: @Korayem : Did you search out things before posting in ?  Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064380/what-happens-in-beginprocessrequest