# Why is MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest() so slow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, session-state

I have an MVC project, and I'm looking at speeding things up. One thing I'm scratching my head over is the BeginProcesRequest() which I have no control over. Using New Relic I found that this method is, on average consuming 90% of the time required for the transaction to complete.

The code in my controller is pretty simple. It has a look for an action session for the user and redirects to their dashboard if it finds one. there isn't any database calls on the actual page. The only written is:

```
if (Session["UserID"] != null)
// Perform actions
```

The BeginProcessRequest() method takes almost 4 seconds as you can see in the screenshot

[image]

This can't be something unique to my site? I'm using a small EC2 instance for the server, and although there are other applications running on the site the CPU and memory stay pretty much at 0 throughout the request.

EDIT - Reviewed the following post:

[What happens in BeginProcessRequest()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064380/what-happens-in-beginprocessrequest)

However as my application is idle when the most time consuming requests take place I can't see how it could be related to competing threads.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens in BeginProcessRequest()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064380/what-happens-in-beginprocessrequest)

Comment: @RowanFreeman, I saw this however my application is actually idle when the worst timeframes occur so I couldn't see how it would relate to competing threads.

Comment: Did you try the solutions listed just to see what happens?

Comment: @Paul in your mvc app , have you implemented custom mvc handler to route requests ?

Comment: @RowanFreeman, yes I removed all references to the session state in my application, have disabled the session state on my home controller and set the outputcache to be active for 1 day, yet it is still pretty slow especially when it's been inactive a while. This is particularly important as the main function of the website is an API, so I need it to be pretty responsive

Comment: @vishalsharma, no there is no custom route handler. In fact not even any custom routes defined.

Comment: I've just found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064380/what-happens-in-beginprocessrequest

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was with IIS, as after I changed the property of idle time-out in the application pool to be one day it now seems to load much faster on initial start.

I also explicitly disabled the session state on my home controller, and ensured that SQL Server's auto close parameter was set to off.