# ASP.NET SessionState Options

Tags: asp.net, performance, deadlock, session-state

Our company runs an asp.net webforms/mvc application and are very likely experiencing the issue described in:

[What happens in BeginProcessRequest()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064380/what-happens-in-beginprocessrequest)

However. Where they are seeing 100ms, we are seeing 100,000ms.  This doesn't sound like our application is just waiting on a lock, it sounds more like it is deadlocking and then hitting the timeout.

To make matters a little more complicated.  There are number of pages where we actually DO want our code to wait for the read/write lock.  We've been using that to keep things from running concurrently.  So I can't just mark everything as read only and move on.

Is this huge wait time in BeginProcessRequest still likely to be locking on SessionState?  (  still trying to find reproducible places where I can switch to read only to see if it fixes it )

Anyone else still need locking and use a different SessionState provider and get better results?