# StateServer - System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginRequest SLOW

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, httpwebrequest, session-state, newrelic

I have got 8 application (VB.NET)  my server running with SQL Server 2008 R2. Each application with a database. Applications are on a server and the database on another server.

Just to let you know:

The server database is on average 30% of CPU  use and the application server has on average 60% of CPU  use.

2 servers with the same configurations. Basic configurations:

- 8CPUs
- 30GB Memory Ram
- Windows Server 2008 R2

We monitor the system 24 hours with the NewRelic. And the big problem: the NewRelic always points to a slowdown caused by "**System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginRequest()**".

[image]

In the second image, we can see that the problem is: "**Application code ( System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginRequest())**"

[image]

I searched a lot on internet and found that maybe it has to do with "sessionState". I use "StateServer"  all the eight applications. (The reason to use "StateServer" was that the applications would be faster.)

Follow the "sessionState" configuration:

```
<sessionState
      cookieless="UseCookies"
      cookieName=".authz"
      mode="StateServer"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
      stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
      timeout="20"
      useHostingIdentity="true" />
```

And everywhere, where I put the object  the session, I use "**Serializable()**". Example:

```
<Serializable()> Public Class Example
```

Anyway, I wanted to explain the situation to you guys. What can I do to make it faster and solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Well, drill down to see what code actually ran. Apparently, BeginRequest called other methods that took this long. It wouldn't make sense to think that BeginRequest itself executed for 150ms. Find out what code ran.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you found information on the this as it relates to [thread agility and session state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064380/what-happens-in-beginprocessrequest/17073158#17073158) so we can skip that.  If you think your missing information you can use [Custom Transactions](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/dotnet-custom-transactions) and [Custom Instrumentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/dotnet-custom-instrumentation) to help the agent see methods that it may be missing.

Even when doing custom instrumentation the duration will not change, however.