# What exactly happens in BeginProcessRequest()? (No session state)

Tags: c#, session, azure, model-view-controller, newrelic

What exactly happens in System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest()? I have a MVC project running on Azure, and with NewRelic it's showing 500ms-1500ms for BeginProcessRequest(). I don't use SessionState (`<sessionState mode="Off" />` in web.config).

I have already looked at this similar question: [What happens in BeginProcessRequest()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064380/what-happens-in-beginprocessrequest)

What exactly is happening here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things other than session state related thread agility that can cause long BeginRequest times.

If New Relic cannot get deep/detailed enough data into the transaction, it rolls it up into the BeginRequest method time. This can also occur if the time could be spent in the database or an external service. This is also demonstrated with asynchronous activity that cannot be tied back to the transaction that fired it.

There are also instances when the application is first started where you can see long BeginRequest times. For your Azure application, you can try turning your app pool's start mode to "Always On" to see cut down on times where your app might have to stop/start, causing long begin requests.

[Here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/troubleshooting/beginrequest-delays-net-thread-agility) is a document that contains some additional information, and [here](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/web-transaction-time-spent-in-beginrequest/6525/6) is a forum post where users without session states have had similar issues.